# 'Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported' again

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I thought, that I understand it and will not have problems with it. But now I'm confused. I have the following code:

```
public class ProjectMemberUserRolesElementViewModel
{
    public string AccessType { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
    public bool Create { get; set; }
    public bool Edit { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
}


var elements = from i in db.ProjectAccessTypes
               select new ProjectMemberUserRolesElementViewModel()
               {
                   AccessType = i.Type,
                   Create = (i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID) != null) ? (from p in i.ProjectMemberAccess where p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID select p.Create).FirstOrDefault() : false,
                   Delete = (i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID) != null) ? i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Delete).FirstOrDefault() : false,
                   Edit = (i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID) != null) ? i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Edit).FirstOrDefault() : false,
                   Read = (i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID) != null) ? i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Read).FirstOrDefault() : false
                };
```

Why I get this error? Where is not primitive type here?

Comment: You can replace `x ? x : false` with `x ?? false`

Comment: Error 2 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'  ;)

Comment: Cast `p.Delete` to `bool?`.  However, the default value of `bool` is `false`, so you don't need that at all.

Comment: `.Where(...) != null` will both never be false and will be untranslatable to SQL (since it is nonsense).

Comment: I thought, default value is null when ProjectMemberAccess does not exist at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple:

```
    elements = from i in db.ProjectAccessTypes
                select new ProjectMemberUserRolesElementViewModel()
                {
                    AccessType = i.Type,
                    Create = i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Create).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Delete = i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Delete).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Edit = i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Edit).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Read = i.ProjectMemberAccess.Where(p => p.ProjectMemberID == ProjectMemberID).Select(p => p.Read).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

The not primitive type is your type ProjectMemberUserRolesElementViewModel. I'm assuming this type is not part of your EF model but part of your view-model classes. Therefore EF cannot project to this type in the compilation to SQL.

Solution: project to an anonymous type instead, use the .AsEnumerable() method to 'go to in-memory mode', and project then to your view-model type.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` will break the subqueries.

Comment: then why code (from i in db.ProjectAccessTypes
                        select new ProjectMemberUserRolesElementViewModel()
                        {
                            AccessType = i.Type
                        }).ToList(); works fine?